# How to embed a video in a java jframe

Tags: java, javafx, video, nullpointerexception

How to embed a video in a java jframe
there is no any tutorials for that

i tried this code but there is an exeption

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class videoFrame extends Application {

    private String VIDEO_URL = getClass().getResource("E:\\Mohamed\\Videos\\The Juggler  المشعوذ (Film)").toString();

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage palco) throws Exception {
        Media media = new Media(VIDEO_URL); // 1
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media); // 2
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer); // 3

        StackPane raiz = new StackPane();
        raiz.getChildren().add(mediaView); // 4
        Scene cena = new Scene(raiz, 600, 400);
        palco.setTitle("Tocando Video em JavaFX");
        palco.setScene(cena);
        palco.show();

        mediaPlayer.play(); // 4
    }
}

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration
```

the error

```
run:
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class videoFrame
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at videoFrame.<init>(videoFrame.java:11)
    ... 13 more
Exception running application videoFrame
C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: At the bottom of your stack trace, you've got `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` `at videoFrame.<init>(videoFrame.java:11)`. Means you're trying to use a a reference to an object that was not initialized in `videoFrame` constructor, which you are not showing here

Comment: Your NPE looks like it is on this line `private String VIDEO_URL = getClass().getResource("E:\\Mohamed\\Videos\\The Juggler  المشعوذ (Film)").toString();` despite the above comment

Comment: @Matt Agreed. I has overlooked the field initialization. Means your file was not found. Can one use an absolute path in `Class.getResource` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is what is giving you the NullPointer. You can fix it by replacing the following line

```
private String VIDEO_URL = getClass().getResource("E:\\Mohamed\\Videos\\The Juggler  المشعوذ (Film)").toString();
```

with this line

```
private String VIDEO_URL =  new File("E:\\Mohamed\\Videos\\The Juggler  المشعوذ (Film)").toURI().toURL().toString()
```

Runnable Example from http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/media.html:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class MediaExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {
        File mediaFile = new File("assets/media/Golden-48569.mp4");
        Media media = new Media(mediaFile.toURI().toURL().toString());

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(mediaView), 1024, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much the error was in the path 